# Number of objects in Logtalk

Tags: list, object, numbers, protocols, logtalk

I've got the protocol:

```
:- protocol(person).
:- public([name/1,
        age/1]).
:- end_protocol.
```

For example, I've made unknown number of objects by using `create_object/4`, how can I get a number of them? It is not a problem to get their names by `current_object/1`, but I need an integer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming only objects (i.e. no categories) implement the `person` protocol, you can compute their number using e.g.

```
count(N) :-
    findall(1, implements_protocol(_,person), L),
    list::length(L, N).
```

Replace the call to `implements_protocol /2` with `conforms_to_protocol/2` if you have hierarchies of objects. You can also generalize the `count/1` predicate by passing the protocol as an argument.

Comment: Ok, it works. Anyway, on the next step I wanted to count objects with some relationships, e.g. count only these objects, where Person::age(young). Have you any idea how to handle that?

Comment: When a SO answer is correct, the proper procedure is to mark it as accepted instead of using a comment for that. Also, don't ask followup questions in comments. Instead, create a new question.